# Updating the database record by id(primary key) using breeze in entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

In my project I am using Entity framework 6 and Breeze for fetching the data.
On client side I am creating a breeze entity in modified state as shown below,

```
var entity = manager.createEntity(entityName);

entity.entityAspect.setModified();//Modifying the state

entity.Id(id);//pushing existing primary key value

entity.IfInactive(true); //updating the record value from false to true

saveChanges(msg).then(function () { //calling save changes
   console.log('Success.');
});
```

But during savechanges it is giving an exception like "The original value for the property 'Id' cannot be set because the property is part of the entity's key."

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [initializer](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/creating-entities.html#entitymanager-createentity) to set the value of the key when the entity is created:

```
var entity = manager.createEntity(entityName, { Id: id });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have used that code but now it is showing me exception like 
" {"The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK__Following__TestId__76D69450\". The conflict occurred in database \"TestDB\", table \"dbo.TestTable\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."} ".

Comment: Thus I have created the Entity as


breeze.manager.createEntity(Table_Name, { Id: id }, breeze.EntityState.Unchanged);

So now it is working fine.

Thank you so much......

Comment: Hi All,

I found the solution for above issue, but still i want to know the exact reason that why it is occurring with Entity framework 6 and breeze-client v 1.5.4?
When i was using EF5 and old version of breeze-client at that time this kind of issue was not occurring.

If possible kindly tell me the reason for it.

Thanking You!